# Name interpreted as date when sorting names in a Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created a Pivot Table with multiple names

One of the name of the people is (for instance) "JUNE". That's Mr. JUNE.

In my Pivot Table, the "Names" are on the "Lign" category on the Pivot Table.

When I sort by "Name" in my Pivot Table, the "JUNE" name appears on top, above the names beginning with "A". It only happens when I put a name that is the same as a month (same with MAY, SEPTEMBER, etc.). It always appears as the first value.

If I change another name and put for instance SEPTEMBER, the Pivot Table sort them as follows:
JUNE
SEPTEMBER
A
B
C

Changing the type of the "Cell" to "Text" format instead of "Standard" doesn't change anything.
THe names are properly sorted outside of the Pivot Table. This only happens in the Pivot Table (even when I recreate it from scratch).

It that a bug? How can I sort properly?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that Excel's automatic formatting leaves cell content as is; just add a `'` first in the cell.

This is an enforced "text" cell.

Any functions called on the cell content *might* need to avoid the first character *(no excel to check in)*.

Comment: I'm not sure that works, I tried to put 'SEPTEMBER and I have the same problem. Changing the formatting of the Pivot Table column to "Text" doesn't change anything either

Comment: If that does NOT work, then I'd call that "strange". Enforced text is not to be hampered with.